# Getting "is_categorical is deprecated" error while using JamesSteinEncoder

Tags: python, machine-learning

Getting below error when trying to fit JamesSteinEncoder

```
encoder = JamesSteinEncoder().fit(X, y)

FutureWarning: is_categorical is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Use is_categorical_dtype instead
  elif pd.api.types.is_categorical(cols):

sklearn.__version__ :  '0.23.2'
```

Code:

```
speed = ['DE','AU','US','FR','GB','KR','AU']
lifespan = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
life = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, np.nan]
index = ['snail', 'pig', 'elephant',
         'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': speed,
                   'lifespan': lifespan,
                  'life':life}, index=index)

df['speed']= df['speed'].astype('category')

 from category_encoders import JamesSteinEncoder
    X = df['speed']
    y = df['lifespan']
    enc = JamesSteinEncoder().fit(X, y)

/Users/*/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/category_encoders/utils.py:21: FutureWarning: is_categorical is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Use is_categorical_dtype instead
  elif pd.api.types.is_categorical(cols):
```

Comment: This seems to be a warning, not an error. Does your code run?

Comment: The warning says that the `is_categorical` method is being replaced by `is_categorical_dtype`; at some point you'll need to check how the new one differs, go through your code and switch to the new one. For now, though, it should still be working with the old one.

Comment: For now, the code works. But i think this is not from my code but from JamesSteinEncoder implementation, as the warning is shown at fit step.

Answer (score 1):

Good thing about python is you can change the source code yourself.
I did it, you can also do this:

Open file with vim, /Users/*/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/category_encoders/utils.py
Goto line 21
change

**elif pd.api.types.is_categorical(cols):**

to

**elif pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(cols):**

save the change and exit vim.
and You are done.
Now you have made the change for yourself and you won't get this warning again.

Comment: In general, editing the source code of an installed package is not a good solution. If this is a warning, there should be some way to modify the client code so that this warning does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

It's a minor chage in ur code.
Change

> elif pd.api.types.is_categorical(cols):

to

> elif **isinstance**(cols.dtype, pd.api.types.**CategoricalDtype**):